# How can I use a data source to find out the ARN of AWS load balancer using terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Here's [the doc](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lb) for AWS LB.

Here's the code sample I came up with, let's imagine I've got this LB:

```
resource "aws_lb" "test" {
  name               = "test-lb-tf"
  internal           = false
  load_balancer_type = "network"
  subnets            = aws_subnet.public.*.id

  enable_deletion_protection = true

  tags = {
    Environment = "Dev"
  }
}
```

then I could enable Shield for it this way:

```
resource "aws_shield_protection" "example" {
  name         = "example"
  resource_arn = aws_lb.test.id

  tags = {
    Environment = "Dev"
  }
}
```

The issue is apparently there's an existing load balancer on AWS in my infra but my tf state was completely removed so I need to use a data source aws or something to retrieve (export) its arn instead of recreating it.

Comment: How did it go? The issue still persists as I see a new question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you lost your state file, you can re-create it by [importing](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/import/index.html) your existing resources into TF. This would be much better then just using a data source for every single resource you lost from under TF control.

But anyway, to use [date source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/lb) you can:

```
data "aws_lb" "test" {
  name = "test-lb-tf"
}

resource "aws_shield_protection" "example" {
  name         = "example"
  resource_arn = data.aws_lb.test.id

  tags = {
    Environment = "Dev"
  }
}
```